# Both PyTorch model and tensor on GPU but getting all tensors not on same device error

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm using a ConvNet built using PyTorch for inference and getting a Runtime Error in the following line:

```
outputs = model(X_batch)
```

The error is

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat1 in method wrapper_CUDA_addmm)
```

My code structure is as follows. I put the model and tensor on the GPU and made a few checks to ensure that they are both on the GPU.

```py
print(args.device) # returns 'cuda'
print(torch.cuda.is_available()) # returns True

model = CNN_MLP(args)
model.to(args.device)

def inference(model, test_dataloader, device='cpu'):
    model.eval()

    metrics = []
    for _, (X_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(tqdm(test_dataloader)):
        X_batch = X_batch.to(args.device)

        print(next(model.parameters()).is_cuda) # returns True
        print(X_batch.is_cuda) # returns True

        outputs = model(X_batch) # Error raised here
        metrics.append(calc_metrics(outputs, y_batch)) # This is a simplified version of the code here

    return aggregate(metrics)

zero_shot_metrics = inference(model, test_dataloader, device=args.device)
```

Other details:

- I'm using a single NVIDIA RTX A4000 GPU, and can confirm this with `nvidia-smi`.
- The `torch` version is `2.0.1+cu118`. `nvidia-smi` shows the CUDA version is 12.0. I'm not sure if this mismatch is significant, but `torch.cuda.is_available()` seems to be working fine.
- The `CNN_MLP` class is defined as follows:

```py
import math
import torch

class CNN_MLP(torch.nn.Module):
    """ CNN-MLP with 1 Conv layer, 1 Max Pool layer, and 1 Linear layer. """

    def __init__(self, seq_len=220, embed_size=64, vocab_size=45, pad_index=0, 
                 stride=1, kernel_size=3, conv_out_size=64, hidden_layer_sizes=[128, 64, 32, 8, 1], dropout_rate=0.25):    
        super(CNN_MLP, self).__init__()
        
        # Embedding layer parameters
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.pad_index = pad_index
        self.hidden_layer_sizes = hidden_layer_sizes
        
        # Conv layer parameters
        self.stride = stride
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.conv_out_size = conv_out_size
        
        # Misc
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        
        # Conv Layers
        self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embed_size, padding_idx=self.pad_index)
        
        self.conv = torch.nn.Conv1d(self.seq_len, self.conv_out_size, self.kernel_size, self.stride)
        self.hidden_act = torch.relu
        self.max_pool = torch.nn.MaxPool1d(self.kernel_size, self.stride)        
        self.flatten = lambda x: x.view(x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*x.shape[2])
        
        # MLP layers
        self.fc_layers = []
        self.hidden_layer_sizes.insert(0, self._linear_layer_in_size())
        for i in range(len(self.hidden_layer_sizes) - 1):
            self.fc_layers.append(torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_layer_sizes[i], self.hidden_layer_sizes[i+1]))
            self.fc_layers.append(torch.nn.ReLU())
            if self.dropout_rate and i != len(self.hidden_layer_sizes) - 2:
                self.fc_layers.append(torch.nn.Dropout(self.dropout_rate))
        self.fc_layers.append(torch.sigmoid)
        
    def _linear_layer_in_size(self):
        out_conv_1 = ((self.embed_size - 1 * (self.kernel_size - 1) - 1) / self.stride) + 1
        out_conv_1 = math.floor(out_conv_1)
        out_pool_1 = ((out_conv_1 - 1 * (self.kernel_size - 1) - 1) / self.stride) + 1
        out_pool_1 = math.floor(out_pool_1)
                            
        return out_pool_1*self.conv_out_size
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.hidden_act(x)
        x = self.max_pool(x)

        x = self.flatten(x)
        
        for layer in self.fc_layers:
            x = layer(x)
        
        return x.squeeze()

    def embed(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.hidden_act(x)
        x = self.max_pool(x)

        x = self.flatten(x)

        for i, layer in enumerate(self.fc_layers):
            if i != len(self.fc_layers) - 1:
                x = layer(x)
        
        return x
```

Comment: how is `CNN_MLP` defined?

Comment: @jodag added the CNN-MLP code link to the "Other details" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `CNN_MLP` the `fc_layers` member needs to be an `nn.Module` because it contains other modules. When you call `.to` on your model, `.to` will be called recursively on all the other members that inhereit `nn.Module`. `fc_layers` is a python list (not an `nn.Module`) so the parameters of these modules are not being transferred to the GPU. The simplest fix would be to replace

```py
        self.fc_layers = []
```

with

```py
        self.fc_layers = torch.ModuleList()
```

(see [`torch.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) for more information).

A better solution would be to make `fc_layers` an [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html#torch.nn.Sequential), and then call it like a normal `nn.Module` during forward.

Comment: Thank you @jodag - working now! Learned something new here as well :)